# Dashboard fragment

Tags: java, android

Hi I am trying to create a Dashboard fragment however, I am missing some lines of code and need your help please! Basically when each item is clicked it opens a new activity.

code:

```
public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {

RelativeLayout rellay_timeline, rellay_friends, rellay_chat, rellay_music,
        rellay_gallery, rellay_map, rellay_weather, rellay_settings;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);


    //SOMETHING NEEDS TO GO HERE*****


    rellay_timeline = view.findViewById(R.id.rellay_timeline);
    rellay_friends = view.findViewById(R.id.rellay_friends);
    rellay_chat = view.findViewById(R.id.rellay_chat);


    rellay_timeline.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity_Timeline.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    rellay_friends.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity_Friends.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    rellay_chat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity_Chat.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    }
```

The error I am getting is saying I need to return something but if I just return view then it does not work. I know that after the onCreateView some code needs to go there but struggling to work out what it is as I have taken code from an Activity tutorial and trying to implement it into a Fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you definitely need to `return view` at the end of the `onCreateView()` method, but also you need to call the parent `onCreateView()` method as well with `super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)`:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
    // Initialize your stuff here
    setupUI(view);
    return view;
}

private void setupUI(View view) {
    rellay_timeline = view.findViewById(R.id.rellay_timeline);
    rellay_friends = view.findViewById(R.id.rellay_friends);
    rellay_chat = view.findViewById(R.id.rellay_chat);

    // The rest of the initialization code goes here...
}
```

You need to call `super()` on every fragment lifecycle method you want to `@Override`.

I refactored the UI initialization logic into a separate private method to improve readability but it's not necessary to do that. I like to keep the fragment lifecycle methods as thin and clean as possible.